# Excel VBA Variable External Link Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot get a VBA formula to work.  I'm trying to bring in cell Q8 from the SalesEast file (later changed to the East Workbook) into the SalesAnalysis Workbook (later changed to the Analysis Workbook).  I don't think INDIRECT can be used because the Analysis Workbook will be opened without having the East Workbook opened.  This macro will be run monthly so the file names will change monthly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub FixSales()

Dim OpenPath As String
Dim SalesAnalysis As String
Dim SalesSupport As String
Dim SalesEast As String
Dim SalesWest As String
Dim Analysis As Workbook
Dim East As Workbook
Dim West As Workbook
Dim Support As Workbook

OpenPath = "F:\budget\Expense Analysis\2018\2018_Q1\"
SalesAnalysis = "Sales Analysis " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 
0), "MM_YY") & ".xlsx"
SalesEast = "Sales East " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 0), 
"MM_YY") & ".xlsx"
SalesWest = "Sales West " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 0), 
"MM_YY") & ".xlsx"
SalesSupport = "Sales Support " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 
0), "MM_YY") & ".xlsx"

Workbooks.Open FileName:=OpenPath & SalesAnalysis
Set Analysis = ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks.Open FileName:=OpenPath & SalesSupport
Set Support = ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks.Open FileName:=OpenPath & SalesEast
Set East = ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks.Open FileName:=OpenPath & SalesWest
Set West = ActiveWorkbook

Analysis.Activate
Sheets("Prior YTD to Curr YTD").Select
Range("C8").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "= ""sum('"" & OpenPath & ""["" & SalesEast & ""]"" & 
""Prior YTD to Curr YTD'!Q8)""'"

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is only referencing a cell in another workbook so no need for sum. Also the single quotes are in the wrong place and there are too many double quotes.

Try this:

```
Range("C8").Formula = "='" & OpenPath & "[" & SalesEast & "]Prior YTD to Curr YTD'!Q8)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that gives me a 1004 Run-time error.

Comment: I finally got it - Range("C8").Formula = "=" & "'" & OpenPath & "[" & SalesEast & "]" & "Prior YTD to Curr YTD" & "'!" & "Q8"